# Program not accepting string input from console

Tags: c, string, struct

I am new to C programing. I am trying to run this program which accepts names of people from the user, and stores those names in an array of structures.

The message to enter the name gets printed on the console, but before the user can enter the string, next statement is displayed. Prog is -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//10 students taken in per batch
#define NUMBER_OF_SEATS 10
#define ROLL_NUM 4

//5 faculty members teach every batch
#define NUMBER_OF_FACULTY 5
#define LENGTH_OF_NAME 50


int main () 
{
//Details of a department
struct dept 
{
    char faculty[NUMBER_OF_FACULTY][LENGTH_OF_NAME];
    int id_students[ROLL_NUM];
    char students[NUMBER_OF_SEATS][LENGTH_OF_NAME];

};

struct dept batch2010[NUMBER_OF_SEATS];
struct dept *point_batch2010 = batch2010;

//Printing the size of the defined strucutre
printf("%lud",sizeof(struct dept));


for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_FACULTY; i++) 
{
    printf("\nEnter name of faculty %d teaching batch of 2010\n",i+1);
    gets(*point_batch2010->faculty);
    point_batch2010++;
}
printf("\n\n");
point_batch2010 = batch2010;

printf("\nFaculty members are:\n");
for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_FACULTY; i++)
{
    puts(*point_batch2010->faculty);
    point_batch2010++;
}
point_batch2010 = batch2010;

**for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i++) 
{
    printf("\nEnter name of student studying in batch of 2010");
    fgets(*point_batch2010->students, LENGTH_OF_NAME, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter roll number of student %d studying in batch 0f 2010\n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",point_batch2010->id_students);
}**

for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i++) 
{
    puts(*batch2010[i].students);
}
return 0;
}
```

The error on the console is -

```
Enter name of student studying in batch of 2010Anita
Enter roll number of student 1 studying in batch 0f 2010
1234
Enter name of student studying in batch of 2010
Enter roll number of student 2 studying in batch 0f 2010
3467
Enter name of student studying in batch of 2010
Enter roll number of student 2 studying in batch 0f 2010
```

I am guessing the error is something to do with the '\n' character, and I could break the code into 2 different for loops but can the issue be sorted within this one loop itself?

Thanks.

Comment: Xcode? How's that related?

Comment: Have been running it on Xcode. It is actually not relevant to the code itself. Added it hastily. Sorry.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure `*point_batch2010->students` does what you think it does.

Comment: It does not work with batch2010[i].students either. Could you elaborate though?

Comment: @userXXX [Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Well, i have tried point_batch2010->faculty in place of *point_batch2010->faculty. It shows a warning: passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1):

Faculty is 2d array. You can try something like this in you for loop asking input from console.

```
gets(point_batch2010->faculty[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` has a bad habit of leaving the newline character from user input on the input stream.  Try adding a second `scanf` after it that consumes a single character (the \n that the user types).
See http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html and children for a more detailed explanation of why `scanf` is evil.
P.S.  There are other problems in your code that some of the other respondents have pointed out, but this should get you through this specific question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i++) 
{
    printf("\nEnter name of student studying in batch of 2010");
    fgets(*point_batch2010->students, LENGTH_OF_NAME, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter roll number of student %d studying in batch 0f 2010\n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",point_batch2010->id_students);
}
```

the problem is [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets) reads in a `\n` whereas [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) leaves it in the buffer.

In the `for` loop after `scanf` reads the input, `\n` is in the buffer and that is then read by `fgets` in the next iteration. `scanf` reads until it reaches space or a newline character, whereas `fgets` reads along with the neline character

You need to do

```
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
```

after your `scanf` line.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend separating human input from scanning (parsing), thus avoiding the evil `scanf()`.

```
for (int i = 0; i<NUMBER_OF_SEATS; i++)  {
  char buffer[LENGTH_OF_NAME];
  printf("\nEnter name of student studying in batch of 2010");
  fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
  sscanf(buffer, "%[^\n]", *point_batch2010->students);
  // using fgets(*point_batch2010->students, ...) puts the '\n' in the name  

  char number[256];
  printf("\nEnter roll number of student %d studying in batch 0f 2010\n",i+1);
  fgets(number, sizeof(number), stdin);
  sscanf(number, "%d",point_batch2010->id_students);
}
```

Note: I think you want your structure to be `int id_students  /*[ROLL_NUM] */;` and `sscanf(number, "%d",/* note the & */ & (point_batch2010->id_students));`